# Slideout menu links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site, http://six03.com/ART which is currently in development. I **thought** I had everything all wrapped up for deployment until I had gone back in 320x480 mode on mobile and none of the links on the slideout menu do not work on any mobile device I have tested, at any resolution, on any page.

I have updated and reverted back to a working copy of jQuery, I have tried `z-index:1;` I have thought of all I could and researched all I could with no avail. Now I am asking for some help here.

I'll do some research in here as well to see if there are any similar problems, or if anyone knows of a thread similar to this, a point in that direction would be greatly appreciated also. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean it 'does not work'?

Comment: Does it do anything? Any errors in console? It works fine on my iphone.

Comment: the nav icon looks wonky in mobile,  check `@media` in css.

Comment: @Punit The links are not clickable on mobile devices I have tested on.

Comment: @DanielD There are no errors in the console.

Comment: @tq On what device? The nav icon looks fine from all the devices I have tested on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you mean only the 'testimonials' and 'contact' links in the menu don't work, on the homepage only.

If this is the case, your problem has nothing to do with jQuery.

Your `.region` element is also positioned, and so it is being rendered over the menu.
Setting `nav {z-index: 1}` and `.region {z-index: 0}` *should* fix the problem, as it will bring the menu over the other positioned content.

Comment: It is the clickable regions on the links on the slideout menu that do not work. the menu itself does what it is supposed to. I'll try those `z-index` fixes and see if they work, which they should.

Comment: Those fixes did not work. I even did them on the media queries in the stylesheet as well.

Comment: just to confirm - do **none** of the links in the menu work? does this happen on all pages, or just the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting rid of the repetitive icon that I had in the menu, I didn't need it, placed a `z-index: 1;` on the `nav` container. I also changed the positioning of the `menu-icon` to `relative` instead of `fixed` and that fixed the problem in the mobile devices I have been able to test in.

Answer (score 0):

unless this was a design feature, the hamburger icon is no longer on the top left and in the hero image when the desktop browser is scaled to narrow width.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That will be taken care of.